# How to perform chisq.test within dplyr nest in R

Tags: r, dplyr, chi-squared

I am having trouble figuring out how to perform a chisq.test within a nested list column of a data frame. If I need to turn the data list-column into a matrix, how do I do that, and then how do I properly refer to the variables for the chisq.test? Take the example below. Thank you!

Here is an example:

```
a <- rep(c('A', 'B'), 10)
b <- rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 10)
c <- as.numeric(rep(c(1:10), each = 2))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c)) %>% 
  mutate(c = as.numeric(c))
```

Is the distribution the same between factor 'b' (levels 'a' and 'b') with 'c' counts, within a subgroups of factor 'a'('A' and 'B')?

```
dfnest <- df %>%
  nest(-a) %>% 
  mutate(chisq_p = map_dbl(data, ~chisq.test(.$b~.$c)$p.value))
```

The last line is what I want to accomplish, but the above is incorrect - how do I use the chisq.test within the list-column data, and insert the p.value into a new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the arguments in the call of `chisq.test` returns the expected result.

```
df %>%
  nest(-a) %>% 
  mutate(chisq_p = map_dbl(data, ~chisq.test(.)$p.value))
```

You can also use an anonymous function.

```
  df %>%
  nest(-a) %>% 
  mutate(chisq_p = map_dbl(data, function(f) { chisq.test(f)$p.value }))
```